# Does Cloudflare speed miniify JS,HTML and JS effect Google analytics traffic?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-analytics, cloudflare

Using Cloudflare on my site to prevent DDOS attacks etc. I get an email from Cloudflare to speed up your site using it, so I check it and did some changes as per that.

[image]

I enable all JS,CSS and HTML Auto Minify but issue is that after this sessions on Google Analytics seems decreasing . Then I uncheck JS and HTML and sessions are up to date.

I want to confirm does Cloudflare speed miniify JS,HTML and JS effect Google analytics traffic?

Answer (score 0):

From documentation it seems like no: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172616-Using-Cloudflare-with-Google-Analytics

> Since Cloudflare does not proxy Google traffic, Cloudflare has no effect on Google Analytics (GA) tracking.  Your site visitors will interact with Google's servers directly.  The Google Analytics Javascript code on your pages is executed by the user's browser, so Google Analytics sees the IP of the user's browser.  The GA Javascript code on your page doesn't talk to your site, so it doesn't interact with Cloudflare.